# H.264 encoded .mp4 not playable on iphone

Tags: iphone, video, podcasts

i have [a video podcast](http://blip.tv/jsconf/rss/itunes/) that i've synced to my iphone.  when i browse the iphone through itunes, it shows that the podcast is on the phone.  when i open the 'Music' app in my phone, the podcasts don't show up.

the video is H.264 encoded `.mp4` files, and my phone has 5 GB free.

**how do i get the videos to show up and play?**

Comment: Have you checked inside the "Videos" app? If it's a video podcast it should show up there. Inconsistent, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it play on your computer in iTunes?  There is a menu choice in iTunes that will convert to iPhone-compatible format.

[image: MENU]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried re-encoding the file with Handbrake or another encoder? The file container may appear compatible, but that's not always the case. Re-encoding should confirm it, plus you can choose iPhone specific compatibility.