Why are some MP4 H264 videos not playable on Safari iPhone?
Note: good answer on SO: MP4 video not playing on Safari iPhone.
In a blog post, I have a video embedded with <video><source src="..." that works for everyone (Firefox, Chrome, at least on PC / Linux / ...), but it specifically doesn't work on Safari iPhone.
Even if you access the video directly by its link on Safari iPhone, it doesn't work either, it only displays a gray background.
Any idea what it could be?
It has been encoded by OBS:
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 864x550 30fps 1989kbps [V: Video Media Handler (h264 high L3.1, yuv420p, 864x550, 1989 kb/s)]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo 3kbps [A: Sound Media Handler [eng] (aac lc, 48000 Hz, stereo, 3 kb/s)]

OBS settings:

Note: I have aleady read these 3 questions, but without any clue about why the MP4 that I linked here doesn't work:
mp4 H264 video won't play in iPhone safari
H.264 encoded .mp4 not playable on iphone
Mp4 file not playing on Ipad/iPhone

Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400233/mp4-h264-video-wont-play-in-iphone-safari?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55828/h-264-encoded-mp4-not-playable-on-iphone?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81257/mp4-file-not-playing-on-ipad-iphone?rq=1

Please read the tag descriptions before using them. It's most likely not a hardware problem, so the iphone tag is not required. And mobile-safari covers the Safari part.

Having said that: The linked questions and answers basically cover the same issue, so technically speaking they all are duplicates. For to further analyze this: They offer ideas on how to analyze the problem and gather more information about the video in question. If you have learned anything additionally from this, please add it to the question.

Thanks for your feedback @nohillside (and sorry for the mis-tagging, my bad ;)). Out of curiosity, does this video play for you https://gget.it/io64/h264test13576.mp4?

No problem. And no, it doesn’t, neither on iOS nor on macOS/QuickTime. It works in VLC.

Thanks for feedback @nohillside. Do you see any error message / log in the browser that explains why it is not playing?

QT shows "The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player", but that we know already.

Your edit today would make an excellent answer. I took a small stab over there with that.
